# How to change the position of a QWidget (QTextEdit) in a scene (PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have an application that consists of a QGraphicsView and a scene. I've created a text box in the scene and I want it to appear whenever I hover over a graphical item and then I want it to disappear when the cursor is not over the graphical item. I want to change the position of that text box so its next to the graphical item. I wrote this code but the message box still appears outside of the scene (or the application to be exact).

```
class graphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(graphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.text.setVisible(False)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.cursorCurrentPosition = event.scenePos()
        self.current = QtCore.QPointF(self.cursorCurrentPosition.x(), self.cursorCurrentPosition.y())
        if len(switchObject_list) > 0:
            for switch in switchObject_list:
                if switch.isUnderMouse():
                    print 'under mouse'
                    self.text.setVisible(True)
                    pos = self.text.mapToParent(self.current.toPoint())
                    self.text.move(pos)
                else:
                    self.text.setVisible(False)
```

Comment: Where are you adding the widget to the scene? Try to move the widget item, not the widget itself.

Comment: `QWidget`s can't be added to scene directly. You need `QGraphicsProxyWidget` to make it possible, but I have a hunch that you don't need to do this at all. Please describe functionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So what my application does is that it allows the user to add graphical items to a scene and I want a text box to appear when the user hovers over the graphical item and then I want the text to disappear when the cursor isn't on the graphical item anymore.@FrankOsterfeld how do I move the widget item? What kind of a difference is there?

Comment: Please start here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsproxywidget.html